# R – first time using projects – does not open csv file even if it is in working directory

Tags: r, csv, rstudio

I created a project in R (my first "project"; before I was just dabbling in a moltitude of files). To do that, first I created a new empty folder in Finder and named it "new_study_results_analysis_R". Then I created the new project referring to that folder. After that, I moved all the files I wanted to analyze in the aferomentioned folder.

At this point I tried to open one of the files:

```
> dat = read.csv("30sub8a10.csv", header = TRUE)
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file '30sub8a10.csv': No such file or directory
```

So I checked:

```
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/S/Users/S/Dropbox/(0.01)__OculusStudy/(0.0)New_study/new_study_results_analysis_R"
```

The working directory is the right one.

I don't understand. How can I open the files?

Comment: What does `list.files()` return?

Comment: Give as much more information as possible because this doesn't lend itself to this type of support very easily.

Comment: @WeihuangWong , list.files() returns "new_study_results_analysis_R.Rproj". So only the project file and not the data files. But the data files are in that finder folder, I just checked. Instead I don't see the .Rproj file in that finder folder.

Comment: Since you're referring to "finder", I assume you're on a Mac. Open up a terminal console, and drag and drop the folder with the data into terminal. Copy the path that appears in terminal and use that in `setwd(...)`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I work on a mac. I tried as you suggested, and I got: **/Users/S/Dropbox/\(0.01\)__Oculus\ Study/\(0.0\)New_study/new_study_results_analysis_R**, but then it does not work with setwd(). It gives me `Error: unexpected '/' in "setwd(/"`, so I took that out. Then I got `Error: unexpected input in "setwd(Users/S/Dropbox/\"`, so I took out all the backward slashes that were added in the terminal console. I still get an error: `Error: unexpected input in "setwd(Users/S/Dropbox/(0.01)_"`

Comment: @WeihuangWong Maybe is an issue with R studio? When I paste the directory there I get: `/Users/S/Dropbox/\(0.01\)__Oculus\ Study/\(0.0\)New_study/new_study_results_analysis_R` that is different from **/Users/S/Dropbox/(0.01)__Oculus\ Study/(0.0)New_study/new_study_results_analysis_R**

Comment: You have to do `setwd("/Users/...")` (with the quotation marks). Compare the string from terminal with the output from `getwd()` in your question: it looks like there's a duplicate "/Users/S/".  I doubt it's an issue with RStudio.

Comment: Since you're using RStudio, you can also just click through to the folder with your data in the "File" panel, and then from the "More" dropdown, choose "Set As Working Directory".

Comment: Thanks, it worked with the quotation marks (oops). I had already used "set as working directory" from the menu, but it was not working, that was the issue – maybe because of the two projects open with two different working directories? It's great that you noticed the duplicate /Users/S/, I will keep an eye on that in the future. Anyway thank you again, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a duplicate "/Users/S/" in the getwd() output. To set the right working directory in a Mac, open up a terminal console, and drag and drop the folder with the data into terminal. Copy the path that appears in terminal and use that in setwd("...").